# Mixed up data on concurrent requests to vue3 SSR app with apollo client

Tags: vuejs3, server-side-rendering, apollo-client, vue-apollo

I'm trying to convert a vue3 SPA that uses an apollo client to SSR with the help of [vite-plugin-ssr](https://vite-plugin-ssr.com/).
I'm facing an issue of mixed-up data on concurrent requests to the express server. The apollo client instance used to be global in the SPA, so I'm trying to create and use a new instance on every request.

I had this file that included the creation of the client, and wrapper functions around the client functions :

```js
// apollo.ts - SPA

const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
    ...
})


export const apolloQuery = async (args) => {
    // some logic

    const response = await apolloClient.query({...})

    // some logic

    return response
}

...
```

Those functions are used in components and store.

The integration [example](https://github.com/brillout/vite-plugin-ssr/tree/main/examples/graphql-apollo-vue) of apollo in vite-plugin-ssr repo uses [@vue/apollo-composable](https://github.com/vuejs/apollo/tree/v4/packages/vue-apollo-composable)

So I tried :

```js
// app.ts

import { DefaultApolloClient } from "@vue/apollo-composable";
import { createApolloClient } from "./path/to/apollo.ts";

const createApp = () => {
   const apolloClient = createApolloClient({...})

   const app = createSSRApp({
       setup() {
          provide(DefaultApolloClient, apolloClient)
       },
       render() {
          return h(App, pageProps || {});
       }
   });
}
```

```js
// apollo.ts - SSR 
import { useApolloClient } from "@vue/apollo-composable"

export const createApolloClient = (args) => {
    // some logic

    return new ApolloClient({...})
}


export const apolloQuery = async (args) => {
    // some logic

    const { client } = useApolloClient()
    const response = await client.query({...})

    // some logic

    return response
}
```

However, this does not work as intended because useApolloClient depends on providing the apollo instance to the app (1), or using the provideApolloClient function (2) :

- (1) this means that calls can only be made during component setup or life cycle hooks, as it leverages the Vue core function getCurrentInstance to inject the client. So I can neither use them in the [onBeforeRender](https://vite-plugin-ssr.com/onBeforeRender) that *vite-plugin-ssr* provides, nor in Vue *onServerPrefetch* hook, nor in the async call to store action.
- (2) provideApolloClient sets the client to a global variable, and the same problem occurs on concurrent requests.

Am I at a dead end and a complete refactor of the apollo client use is needed, or am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe you should follow [this guide](https://v4.apollo.vuejs.org/guide-advanced/ssr.html#create-apollo-client).

Comment: Hi @Duannx thanks for the link ! This is actually one of the guides I followed, but this does not resolve the root problem.

Comment: The difficulty here is that you use two plugins on top of Vue. So when the conflict happens, it's so hard to debug because each plugin has its own logic. I do use Apollo client together with SSR as well but I neither use `vite-plugin-ssr` nor `vue-apollo`. It's a little harder to setup SSR but it avoids the kind of problems like this in the long term

Comment: Actually the debug was not so bad. I'm just looking for someone who was successful using both in the way described above.